# Entity Framework. Как указать пароль и логин пользователя во время выполнения

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

Имеется приложение на C# которое через Entity Framework подключается к Sql Server 2012. Не могу понять как явно указать логин и пароль пользователя базы данных sql server во время выполнения. Я просто добавил entity к проекту, указал базу данных, он создал модель. Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться дальше. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Параметры подключения к SQL Server указываются в connectionString.
В EF параметры подключения можно передать в конструктор [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
DbContext("server=some;database=dbname;user id=uid;password=pwd")
```

Для создания строки можно использовать SqlConnectionStringBuilder.

```
var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() {
    UserID = "...",
    Password = "...",
};
var cs = sb.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой-же задачей и решил ее следующим образом (да простят меня гуру).

После создания модели в проект добавляется файл с расширением `edmx` в котором в свою очередь находится конструктор контекста `ModelName.Context.cs`. В конструкторе я добавил код переписывающий строку подключения:

```cs
public Db() : base("name=Db") {
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = Program.ConnectionString;
}
```

После чего нужно лишь при старте программы запрашивать пароль у пользователя, либо создавать строку подключения с помощью [Microsoft Data Connection Dialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/). Тут необходимо уточнить, что приведенный код необходимо будет добавлять каждый раз после обновления модели, т.к. класс является авто-генерируемым.

Также, как уже [ответил Stack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477675), строку подключения можно передать в конструктор при создании контекста:

```cs
string connectionString = null;
var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() {
    UserID = "...",
    Password = "...",
};
connectionString = sb.ConnectionString;

// or use Microsoft Data Connection Dialog
using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI;
using(var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog()) {
    dialog.DataSources.Add(DataSource.SqlDataSource);
    dialog.SelectedDataSource = DataSource.SqlDataSource;
    dialog.ConnectionString = savedConnectionString ?? "";
    DialogResult userChoice = DataConnectionDialog.Show(dialog);
    if(userChoice == DialogResult.OK) {
        connectionString = dialog.ConnectionString;
    }
}

using(var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString)) {
    // anything...
}
```

Описание перегруженных конструкторов DbContext можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_0).