# подставить пароль в строку подключения

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть приложение WinForms + entity-framework + MS SQL.
Если задать всю строку подключения в app.config
или если задать всю строку подключения в коде, то все работает.

```
class UserContext : DbContext
{

    public UserContext()
        : base("DBConnection")
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "data source=server;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=12345678";
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Но мне нужно взять строку подключения из app.config (в которой удален пароль) и в коде UserContext подставить пароль. Похожий ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477671/entity-framework-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/477675#477675), но не до конца понял, как подставить.

Для чего - чтобы совсем в открытом виде не хранить пароль (разбирать программу никто не будет, но в конфиге в открытом виде тоже храниться не хочется)

Дополнения после первого ответа: 
это строка в app.config

```
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=server;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1}"
```

так я выполнил добавление пароля в коде

```
base.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = string.Format(Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "test", "12345678");
```

такая получилось строка при наведении во время остановки Database.Connection.ConnectionString

```
 "data source=server;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=12345678"
```

Создал пустое приложение. Есть только класс

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст

```
    class UserContext : DbContext
{

    public UserContext()
        : base("DBConnection")
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = string.Format(Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "test", "12345678");

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

И кнопка, где идет считывание таблицы

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            var users = db.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Как я понимаю: если в app.config есть строка подключения, то он берет её. Если её нет, то берет из Database.Connection.ConnectionString.

Answer (score 0):

```
Database.Connection.ConnectionString = 
  string.Format("Password={0};data source=server;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test", 
    "12345678");
```

Comment: Поставил точку остановки. Строка сформировалась с паролем и логином (я заменил и пароль и логин таким способом), но при попытке получить данные из базы пишет "Login failed for user '{0}'."

Comment: @Shpunder Покажите Ваш код с этими изменениями.

Comment: выше показал свои действия и результат

Comment: Вы где-то (вероятно, в другом месте) используете строку подсоединения без вызова `string.Format`.

Comment: using (UserContext db = new UserContext()) - почему то в db попадает строка без форматирования. Хотя если пройти по шагам, то сразу попадаю в код, где идет вызов со string.Format.

Comment: выше добавил весь код приложения тестового

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема. В App.config есть строка подключения. Создана автоматически при добавлении Entity Data Model. А идея в том, что пользователь сам вводит имя и пароль, но передать параметры в строку подключения надо безопасно.
Вышел из ситуации таким образом (в ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionName"] DefaultConnectionName это имя подключения из App.Config) :

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;//надо добавить ссылку


public partial class Context : DbContext
{
   static public string ConnString(string defaultConnStr)

   {
     SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
     builder.ConnectionString = defaultConnStr;
     builder.UiserId = "newuserId";
     builder.Password = "newPassword";
     return builder.ConnectionString;
   }

   Context() : base(ConnString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionName"].ConnectionString)) {}
}
```